# Is django overkill for building a simple python-based local web app to control cameras on a network?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, network-programming

**Disclaimer:** I don't a whole lot about web app development, but i've been tasked with building one and I want to make sure i'm on the right path here.

**Goal:** There are a bunch of cameras on a network and I want to build a local web app that allows the user to click on a button (there's a button for each camera) and it will trigger an alarm on that camera.

**The idea I had in mind:**

1) First create the functionality to be able to connect to the camera and send the command to trigger the alarm

2) Next, start building a front end to make it look nice (I think this is the more intensive part).

I planned on building the front end using python and django, but **is django overkill for this?** I read that bottle is a very simple web app framework, and I'm wondering if I should go with something smaller and more lightweight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct in Django being a little overpowered for a simple app like this.  It's large and opinionated and might be a bit more trouble than it's worth.

Something like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is a lot lighter and makes more sense for a project of this scale in my opinion. But there's also something to be said about familiarity with a framework and how well you can perform in each, so it's really developers choice.  You will get the job done with either.

Comment: Would you recommend that I have a database for all of the cameras on the network, or would it be sufficient to maybe have all the IPs in a list? I'm not exactly sure how many cameras i'm dealing with yet, it could potentially be in the hundreds.

Comment: It definitely wouldn't hurt to have them stored in a DB. Then it'd be pretty trivial to add metadata, say number of times the alarm has been triggered, or Users who triggered the alarm and how many times. Then the data will persist if your program stops executing for whatever reason. 

A DB is going to easily be able to handle hundreds of cameras, no problem.

Comment: Is there a particular database you would recommend for a beginner? Right now i'm inclined to use MySQL just because I know it's name for the most part.

Comment: Definitely worth sitting through some SQL tutorials and then you'll be able to tackle either MySQL or Postgres without too much trouble. (I'm partial to Postgres, but they're quite similar). Remember Google is your best friend. Good luck!